# Symfony2 - Custom validator and dependancy injection

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, customvalidator

I am trying to use dependancy injection for a custom validator, in order to be able to use the entityManager.

I followed the Symfony Example: [Dependency Injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies), but I am allways getting this error message:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'isdoi' not found in
>   /home/milos/workspace/merrin3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Validator/ConstraintValidatorFactory.php
>   line 68

Here are my classes:

**1. The IsDOI class:**

```
    <?php
    namespace Merrin\MainBundle\Validator\Constraints;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

    /**
     * @Annotation
    */
    class IsDOI extends Constraint
    {
    public $message_publisher_DOI = 'The Publisher DOI abbreviation does not correspond to the DOI you filled in !';
    public $message_journal_DOI = 'No journal found with the DOI you filled in !';
    public $journal;
    public $doiAbbreviation;

     public function validatedBy() {
            return "isdoi";
        }

        public function getTargets()
        {
            return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
        }
    }
```

**2. The IsDOIValidator class:**

```
<?php

namespace Merrin\MainBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class IsDOIValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {       
        $em_mdpipub = $this->entityManager('mdpipub');
        //Do some tests here...

    }
}
```

**3. Service:**

```
merrin.main.validator.isdoi:
    class:  Merrin\MainBundle\Validator\Constraints\IsDOIValidator
    arguments: 
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Where am I wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have wrong service file, when You add tags and alias you could use "isdoi" name

```
merrin.main.validator.isdoi:
    class:  Merrin\MainBundle\Validator\Constraints\IsDOIValidator
    arguments: 
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: isdoi }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're telling Symfony2 that the validator class for your constraint is `isdoi` (`validateBy method`). However, your validator is `IsDOIValidator`.

You must use :

```
public function validateBy()
{
    return "IsDOIValidator";
}
```

However, if your `Constraint` class name is `IsDOI`, Symfony will automatically look for `IsDOIValidator` as a `ConstraintValidator`. The default behavior for `validateBy` is to append "Validator" to the constraint name, and look for the class with this name. So if you do not overload `validateBy`, Symfony2 will automatically search for `IsDOIValidator`.