# Custom validator accessed twice

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, customvalidator

I have a custom validator on my Symfony2 project.
The validation works fine, but the method is somehow accessed twice.

Here is my custom validator: [My other resolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671384/symfony2-custom-validator-and-dependancy-injection)

The problem is the next: [image]

As you can see, the error message is displayed twice. When I am trying to var dump something in the validate method, the vardump is also displayed twice. Any idea why the validate is called twice? This is called when I am using $form->bind($request); in my controller.

**EDIT**

Here is the twig template:

```
{% extends 'MerrinMainBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block page_title %} 
MDPI Conversion system (Merrin) 3.0 - New Conversion
{% endblock %}

{% block main %} 
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('user-notice') %}
    <div class="flash-notice">
        {% autoescape false %}
        {{ flashMessage }}
        {% endautoescape %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<h1>Create New Manuscript</h1>
{% if valid == false %}
        <div class="error">
         {{ form_errors(form) }}
         {{ form_errors(form.doi) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.publisher) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.file) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>   
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

And the controller call

```
public function createAction()
{       
    $em_scipub      = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em_mdpipub     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('mdpipub');

    $enquiry = new Manuscript();

    $formType   = new NewManuscriptType();
    $form       = $this->createForm($formType, $enquiry);

    $request    = $this->getRequest();
    $valid      = true;
    $error      = '';

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            ... do something ...

            $em_scipub->persist($enquiry);

            $em_scipub->flush();

            $flash_message = "<a href='edit/".$enquiry->getId()."'>New Manuscript</a> sucessfully created.";

                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('user-notice', $flash_message);

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MerrinMainBundle_new'));
        }
        else
            $valid = false;
    }

    $path = $this->generateUrl('MerrinMainBundle_new');

    return $this->render('MerrinMainBundle:Pages:new_conversion.html.twig.twig', array(
            'valid' => $valid,
            'path'  => $path,
            'form'  => $form->createView(),
    ) );
}
```

**EDIT2:**

The validate function:

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{       
    $doi = $value->getDoi();

    preg_match('/[^\/]+/i', $doi, $publisherDoiAbbr);
    if($publisherDoiAbbr[0] !== $value->getPublisher()->getDoiAbbreviation()) {
        $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message_publisher_DOI);
    }
    else {
        preg_match("/[a-z]+/",$doi, $journalDoiAbbr);

        $em_mdpipub = $this->entityManager;
        $journal = $em_mdpipub->getRepository('MerrinMdpiPubBundle:Journal')->findOneBy(array('doi_abbreviation' => $journalDoiAbbr));

        if($journal == null) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message_journal_DOI);
        }
    }

    preg_match('/\d*$/i', $doi, $doiNumericPart);
    if(strlen($doiNumericPart[0]) < 8) {
        $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message_volume_issue_firstpage_DOI);  
    }   
}
```

And the twig template:

```
{% extends 'MerrinMainBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block page_title %} 
MDPI Conversion system (Merrin) 3.0 - New Conversion
{% endblock %}

{% block main %} 
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('user-notice') %}
<div class="flash-notice">
    {% autoescape false %}
    {{ flashMessage }}
    {% endautoescape %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
<h1>Create New Manuscript</h1>
{% if valid == false %}
        <div class="error">
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.doi) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.publisher) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.file) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        <div style="float:left;">
            <table width="700">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_label(form.doi) }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_widget(form.doi, { 'attr': {'size': 40} })  }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_label(form.publisher) }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_widget(form.publisher) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td>
                        {{ form_label(form.file) }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_widget(form.file) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="submit-confirm-button" type="submit" name="update-text" value="submit" />
                        <a class="cancel-link" href="{{ path('MerrinMainBundle_homepage' ) }}">Cancel</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT 3:**

Here is how I am applying the validator to the entity:

```
/**
 * Manuscript
 *
 * @IsDOI()
 * @ORM\Table(name="manuscripts")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Merrin\MainBundle\Repository\ManuscriptRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * 
 */
class Manuscript
{
....
}
```

**EDIT 4:**

When I try to vardump the

```
$form->getErrors();
```

I am getting an array with two values:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=&gt;
  object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)#507 (4) {
    ["message":"Symfony\Component\Form\FormError":private]=&gt;
    string(77) "The Publisher DOI abbreviation does not correspond to the DOI you filled in !"
    ["messageTemplate":protected]=&gt;
    string(77) "The Publisher DOI abbreviation does not correspond to the DOI you filled in !"
    ["messageParameters":protected]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["messagePluralization":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
  }
  [1]=&gt;
  object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)#542 (4) {
    ["message":"Symfony\Component\Form\FormError":private]=&gt;
    string(77) "The Publisher DOI abbreviation does not correspond to the DOI you filled in !"
    ["messageTemplate":protected]=&gt;
    string(77) "The Publisher DOI abbreviation does not correspond to the DOI you filled in !"
    ["messageParameters":protected]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["messagePluralization":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `twig template` and the `controller action`?

Comment: @byf-ferdy, sure, I will edit my question.

Comment: also show us the validation definition please, and the code for the custom validator. Also, please post the complete version of the twig template, just in case

Comment: @saamorim, I will re edit my question.

Comment: @Milos how did you setup the validation, through validation.yml? If so, reedit the post again please

Comment: @saamorim, right, here is how my validation.yml looks like: `Merrin\MainBundle\Entity\Manuscript:
    constraints:
        - Merrin\MainBundle\Validator\Constraints\IsDOI: ~`

Comment: If you `var_dump($form->getErrors())` and `foreach ($form as $field) { var_dump($form->getErrors()) }` do you see duplicated errors? On the same field? On different fields? Between the form and the fields?

Comment: @ThomasPotaire, The first getErrors returns me the error twice: An array with two arrays inside, with the same error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible if you are using [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) and apply validator to several groups. And what `@IsDOI()` annotation mean? If its apply validation possible that you first add validator in `validation.yml` and second via this custom annotation.

Comment: Excellent @forgottenbas, thank you so much. In fact, I was adding the validation in the validation.yml and also in the Entity as @IsDOI(), so I was validating twice. I have understood that we need to add the validator in both places, not that the plaec is optionnal.

Comment: Heh, I spent a lot of trying to resolve this and thx to you, It was done. You can give me a +1, will be great...

Comment: Sure :) Small bugs taking up the most of time

Comment: could someone point out how "this is possible if you are using validation groups" phrase please? I'm having the same issue but no duplicate annotations

Comment: I had this very problem and although this post is now over 8 years old, it helped me immensely. Beware of adding the constraint via annotation, in your entity, *and* setting it on your form class in its `configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)` method. One or the other!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're rendering it twice.

Here:

```
     {{ form_errors(form) }}
```

followed by:

```
     {{ form_errors(form.doi) }}
     {{ form_errors(form.publisher) }}
     {{ form_errors(form.file) }}
```

Since you are displaying the errors in single place, I recommend using only the first method.

As stated in the [form_errors twig reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#reference-forms-twig-errors):

> **form_errors(view)**
>
> *Renders any errors for the given field.*
>
> ```
> {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
>
> {# render any "global" errors #}
> {{ form_errors(form) }}
> ```

Comment: Thank you saamorim. So, theoreticaly, If I will remove all the form_errors, except the frist one: `{{ form_errors(form) }}`, I should the error only once. This is unfortunately not the case. Any idea?

Comment: try to debug the form errors to see which one of them throws an error. Do you use [error_bubbling](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling)?

Comment: @Saamorim - By default, the global errors will not list the field-specific errors so the issue is elsewhere

Comment: @ThomasPotaire, do you have an idea where the error can come from?

Comment: @Milos I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a lot of custom code (EntityManager, Validator) it is hard to tell the error with the amount of code you provide because it's not possible to recreate the error locally.

**But here are my suggestions:**

1. In your **Validator** there are two possible cases the following violation gets thrown

   ```
   $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message_publisher_DOI);
   ```

   On both occasions the error message is the same. Maybe both of these cases apply. Try to *debug* this by adding an individual error message for both cases.
2. I don't know the code of your **Form**-Class but maybe you apply your custom validator to multiple fields? Also remove validations for each field individually to see where the duplicate error message is thrown.
3. One last mistake I can imagine would be a custom **Form-Template**. If you have one check whether or not you maybe call the `{{ form_error(form) }}` block or any other block multiple times.

I hope one of my suggestions did help you.

Comment: Thank you byf-ferdy. Some comments: 1. In my Validator, the `$this->context->addViolation($constraint->message_publisher_DOI);` is used only once, not twice. I also mentioned that the method Validate is called twice for some reason, so this method is ok. 2. The custom validator is applied to the Entity class, not to a field. 3. The `{{ form_error(form) }}` is called only once.

Comment: @Milos fair points. Where do you apply the **Validator** to the **Entity**?

Comment: the validator is applied in the entity itself, I edite my question with the beggining of the entity.